# VSCode TypeScript rxjs map() operator loses type after enough repetitions

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, rxjs, overloading

My question here is; What's causing vscode to lose track of the type and if there is any way of extending it's capability. Secondarily any possible workaround would be appreciated.

I've done some googling and found a couple issues related to infinite type recursion getting abandoned but I'm not sure if this falls in that boat or not. If it is that I think this instance is pretty interesting given Rxjs is such a widely used library and this problem can be triggered after only 9 map calls in a given pipe.

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35533
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29511

See below for a simple code fragment that reproduces the issue in vscode.

```js
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

const test = new Subject<string>();

test.pipe(
  map(msg => msg),
  map(msg => msg),
  map(msg => msg),
  map(msg => msg),
  map(msg => msg),
  map(msg => msg),
  map(msg => msg),
  map(msg => msg),
  map(msg => msg),
  map(msg => msg) // <---- type is lost here, msg becomes any!
);
```

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5c68e208512dd0f3ba1aafbf3e592592ec13db9b/src/internal/Observable.ts#L307-L319

Comment: Looks like this is really just an Rxjs limitation here with only 9 possible piped operators with anything above that reverting back to any and returning Observable<{}>. If you'd like to formulate this as an answer we can wrap this thing up.

Comment: The workaround is using a second `pipe` after 9 operators. `test.pipe(9-operators).pipe(more-operators)`

Comment: It's also possible to provide a workaround via adding custom typings for more arguments, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76455048/4244580)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as @cartant mentioned [rxjs-pipes](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5c68e208512dd0f3ba1aafbf3e592592ec13db9b/src/internal/Observable.ts#L307-L319) gain types via [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads). As you can see the overloads are only applied up to 9 arguments (operators). To avoid loosing types you can chain multiple pipes:

```
const source$ = pipe(
  ...
  map(foo => foo),
  ...
).pipe(
  ...
  map(foo => foo),
  ...
)
```

Check the type of `source$` in [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-funcion-overload-pipe-chaining?file=index.ts) running stackblitz.

Easy sample overload:

```
class Foo {
  add<T>(arg: T): T
  add<T, T2>(arg1: T, arg2: T2): T | T2
  add<T, T2>(arg1: T, arg2: T2, ...args: any): any
  add(...args: any) {
    return args.reduce((acc: any, curr: any) => acc + ' ' + curr, '')
  }
}

const foo = new Foo();

// type: 'first' | 'second'
const add1 = foo.add('first', 'second');
console.log(add1);

// type: any
const add2 = foo.add('first', 'second', 'third');
console.log(add2);
```

The example itself is stupid but I hope it explains the reason why it gets `any` at some point.

Comment: A great find, Jonathan! Thank you for providing the answer and solution to my problem. I couldn't make sense of why my type got lost at one point in my mix of map and mergeMap (with their own map-calls) operator functions. It is as you pointed out: after 9 map-calls, the type floats off into space and is never seen again.