# Angular, observable pipe limit?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, rxjs-observables

I'm doing this in one of my route guards...

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    // go through each check sequentially, stop process if one does throwError
    return of(true).pipe( // Is there a limit to operators in a pipe???
      switchMap(() => of(true)), // simplified for this post...usually call a function that returns
      switchMap(() => of(true)),
      switchMap(() => of(true)),
      switchMap(() => of(true)),
      switchMap(() => of(true)),
      switchMap(() => of(true)),
      switchMap(() => of(true)),
      switchMap(() => of(true)),
      // if any function returns throwError, we skip other checks
      catchError(() => of(false))
    );
  }
```

I'm running into an error.  If there is one more switchMap added to the list, VSCode tells me...
"Type 'Observable<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.
Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.ts(2322)"

Can somebody explain to me why that's the case?  I can't figure it out and find related issues.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is pretty well explained in [this github issue](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/4221#issuecomment-426774631).

The gist of it is that only 9 operators are supported - any more and it will fall back to type `Observable<{}>` since they have to manually type everything up to 9 operators.

**Use multiple pipes (maintains typesafety after the 9nth entry)**

If you still want to maintain typesafety but add more than 9 operators, just call the pipe function again.

```js
source$
  .pipe(
    tap(() => {}),
    tap(() => {}),
    tap(() => {}),
    tap(() => {}),
    tap(() => {}),
    tap(() => {}),
    tap(() => {}),
    tap(() => {}),
    tap(() => {})
  )
  .pipe(
    // Add the next operators after the 9nth here
    tap(() => {}) 
  )
```

**Manually assert the resulting type**

Alternatively, you can add a manual type assertion at the end. Beware though: After the 9nth operator, the type will be infered as `Observable<{}>`, effectively losing typesafety.

```
const source$:Observable<boolean> = of(true)
  .pipe(
    tap(() => {}),
    tap(() => {}),
    tap(() => {}),
    tap(() => {}),
    tap(() => {}),
    tap(() => {}),
    tap(() => {}),
    tap(() => {}),
    tap(() => {}),
    // Typesafety is lost here
    tap(() => {}),
    tap(() => {}),

  // Manually assert the type at the end 
  // Beware that the compiler will allow pretty much anything here,
  // so "as Observable<string>" would work, even though it'd be wrong.
  ) as Observable<boolean>;
```

Comment: No need, this behaves exactly the same as if you would have everything in a single pipe. This is only needed to get proper type inference.

Comment: So just put a catchError in the second pipe?

Comment: If you want to have the catchError be the last thing your observable does (as in your example above), yes.

Comment: Sorry. I should have been more clear in the post...each of those switchMaps will either return of(true) or throwError();

Comment: In that case you most likely want the catchError at the end - so it catches all of your errors. 
Just think of this solution as if you had all the operators in a single `pipe()` - in fact, you can put them in a single pipe and assert the type at the end (which is what the linked issue offers as a solution). This behaves exactly the same in the exact same order.

Comment: if you rewrite your answer to use the suggestion from your link, I'll accept the answer.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm personally not a fan of that solution since it stops the type inference chain in your pipe - basically losing all typesafety after the 9nth entry. I can include the suggestion in the link however :)

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, it's also possible to provide simple own typings file until it will be fixed withing `rxjs` itself. Make sure this file included via `tsconfig.json`

```ts
// rxjs-pipe.d.ts
import { OperatorFunction } from 'rxjs';

declare module 'rxjs' {
    class Observable<T> {
        pipe<A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J>(
            op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>,
            op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>,
            op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>,
            op4: OperatorFunction<C, D>,
            op5: OperatorFunction<D, E>,
            op6: OperatorFunction<E, F>,
            op7: OperatorFunction<F, G>,
            op8: OperatorFunction<G, H>,
            op9: OperatorFunction<H, I>,
            op10: OperatorFunction<I, J>,
        ): Observable<unknown>;

        pipe<A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K>(
            op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>,
            op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>,
            op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>,
            op4: OperatorFunction<C, D>,
            op5: OperatorFunction<D, E>,
            op6: OperatorFunction<E, F>,
            op7: OperatorFunction<F, G>,
            op8: OperatorFunction<G, H>,
            op9: OperatorFunction<H, I>,
            op10: OperatorFunction<I, J>,
            op11: OperatorFunction<J, K>,
        ): Observable<unknown>;

        pipe<A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L>(
            op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>,
            op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>,
            op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>,
            op4: OperatorFunction<C, D>,
            op5: OperatorFunction<D, E>,
            op6: OperatorFunction<E, F>,
            op7: OperatorFunction<F, G>,
            op8: OperatorFunction<G, H>,
            op9: OperatorFunction<H, I>,
            op10: OperatorFunction<I, J>,
            op11: OperatorFunction<J, K>,
            op12: OperatorFunction<K, L>,
        ): Observable<unknown>;

        pipe<A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M>(
            op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>,
            op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>,
            op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>,
            op4: OperatorFunction<C, D>,
            op5: OperatorFunction<D, E>,
            op6: OperatorFunction<E, F>,
            op7: OperatorFunction<F, G>,
            op8: OperatorFunction<G, H>,
            op9: OperatorFunction<H, I>,
            op10: OperatorFunction<I, J>,
            op11: OperatorFunction<J, K>,
            op12: OperatorFunction<K, L>,
            op13: OperatorFunction<L, M>,
        ): Observable<unknown>;

        pipe<A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N>(
            op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>,
            op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>,
            op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>,
            op4: OperatorFunction<C, D>,
            op5: OperatorFunction<D, E>,
            op6: OperatorFunction<E, F>,
            op7: OperatorFunction<F, G>,
            op8: OperatorFunction<G, H>,
            op9: OperatorFunction<H, I>,
            op10: OperatorFunction<I, J>,
            op11: OperatorFunction<J, K>,
            op12: OperatorFunction<K, L>,
            op13: OperatorFunction<L, M>,
            op14: OperatorFunction<M, N>,
        ): Observable<unknown>;

        pipe<A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O>(
            op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>,
            op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>,
            op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>,
            op4: OperatorFunction<C, D>,
            op5: OperatorFunction<D, E>,
            op6: OperatorFunction<E, F>,
            op7: OperatorFunction<F, G>,
            op8: OperatorFunction<G, H>,
            op9: OperatorFunction<H, I>,
            op10: OperatorFunction<I, J>,
            op11: OperatorFunction<J, K>,
            op12: OperatorFunction<K, L>,
            op13: OperatorFunction<L, M>,
            op14: OperatorFunction<M, N>,
            op15: OperatorFunction<N, O>,
        ): Observable<unknown>;

        pipe<A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P>(
            op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>,
            op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>,
            op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>,
            op4: OperatorFunction<C, D>,
            op5: OperatorFunction<D, E>,
            op6: OperatorFunction<E, F>,
            op7: OperatorFunction<F, G>,
            op8: OperatorFunction<G, H>,
            op9: OperatorFunction<H, I>,
            op10: OperatorFunction<I, J>,
            op11: OperatorFunction<J, K>,
            op12: OperatorFunction<K, L>,
            op13: OperatorFunction<L, M>,
            op14: OperatorFunction<M, N>,
            op15: OperatorFunction<N, O>,
            op16: OperatorFunction<O, P>,
        ): Observable<unknown>;

        pipe<A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q>(
            op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>,
            op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>,
            op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>,
            op4: OperatorFunction<C, D>,
            op5: OperatorFunction<D, E>,
            op6: OperatorFunction<E, F>,
            op7: OperatorFunction<F, G>,
            op8: OperatorFunction<G, H>,
            op9: OperatorFunction<H, I>,
            op10: OperatorFunction<I, J>,
            op11: OperatorFunction<J, K>,
            op12: OperatorFunction<K, L>,
            op13: OperatorFunction<L, M>,
            op14: OperatorFunction<M, N>,
            op15: OperatorFunction<N, O>,
            op16: OperatorFunction<O, P>,
            op17: OperatorFunction<P, Q>,
        ): Observable<unknown>;

        pipe<A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q>(
            op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>,
            op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>,
            op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>,
            op4: OperatorFunction<C, D>,
            op5: OperatorFunction<D, E>,
            op6: OperatorFunction<E, F>,
            op7: OperatorFunction<F, G>,
            op8: OperatorFunction<G, H>,
            op9: OperatorFunction<H, I>,
            op10: OperatorFunction<I, J>,
            op11: OperatorFunction<J, K>,
            op12: OperatorFunction<K, L>,
            op13: OperatorFunction<L, M>,
            op14: OperatorFunction<M, N>,
            op15: OperatorFunction<N, O>,
            op16: OperatorFunction<O, P>,
            op17: OperatorFunction<P, Q>,
        ): Observable<unknown>;

        pipe<A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R>(
            op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>,
            op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>,
            op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>,
            op4: OperatorFunction<C, D>,
            op5: OperatorFunction<D, E>,
            op6: OperatorFunction<E, F>,
            op7: OperatorFunction<F, G>,
            op8: OperatorFunction<G, H>,
            op9: OperatorFunction<H, I>,
            op10: OperatorFunction<I, J>,
            op11: OperatorFunction<J, K>,
            op12: OperatorFunction<K, L>,
            op13: OperatorFunction<L, M>,
            op14: OperatorFunction<M, N>,
            op15: OperatorFunction<N, O>,
            op16: OperatorFunction<O, P>,
            op17: OperatorFunction<P, Q>,
            op18: OperatorFunction<Q, R>,
        ): Observable<unknown>;

        pipe<A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S>(
            op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>,
            op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>,
            op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>,
            op4: OperatorFunction<C, D>,
            op5: OperatorFunction<D, E>,
            op6: OperatorFunction<E, F>,
            op7: OperatorFunction<F, G>,
            op8: OperatorFunction<G, H>,
            op9: OperatorFunction<H, I>,
            op10: OperatorFunction<I, J>,
            op11: OperatorFunction<J, K>,
            op12: OperatorFunction<K, L>,
            op13: OperatorFunction<L, M>,
            op14: OperatorFunction<M, N>,
            op15: OperatorFunction<N, O>,
            op16: OperatorFunction<O, P>,
            op17: OperatorFunction<P, Q>,
            op18: OperatorFunction<Q, R>,
            op19: OperatorFunction<R, S>,
        ): Observable<unknown>;

        pipe<A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T>(
            op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>,
            op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>,
            op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>,
            op4: OperatorFunction<C, D>,
            op5: OperatorFunction<D, E>,
            op6: OperatorFunction<E, F>,
            op7: OperatorFunction<F, G>,
            op8: OperatorFunction<G, H>,
            op9: OperatorFunction<H, I>,
            op10: OperatorFunction<I, J>,
            op11: OperatorFunction<J, K>,
            op12: OperatorFunction<K, L>,
            op13: OperatorFunction<L, M>,
            op14: OperatorFunction<M, N>,
            op15: OperatorFunction<N, O>,
            op16: OperatorFunction<O, P>,
            op17: OperatorFunction<P, Q>,
            op18: OperatorFunction<Q, R>,
            op19: OperatorFunction<R, S>,
            op20: OperatorFunction<S, T>,
        ): Observable<unknown>;

        pipe<A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U>(
            op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>,
            op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>,
            op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>,
            op4: OperatorFunction<C, D>,
            op5: OperatorFunction<D, E>,
            op6: OperatorFunction<E, F>,
            op7: OperatorFunction<F, G>,
            op8: OperatorFunction<G, H>,
            op9: OperatorFunction<H, I>,
            op10: OperatorFunction<I, J>,
            op11: OperatorFunction<J, K>,
            op12: OperatorFunction<K, L>,
            op13: OperatorFunction<L, M>,
            op14: OperatorFunction<M, N>,
            op15: OperatorFunction<N, O>,
            op16: OperatorFunction<O, P>,
            op17: OperatorFunction<P, Q>,
            op18: OperatorFunction<Q, R>,
            op19: OperatorFunction<R, S>,
            op20: OperatorFunction<S, T>,
            op21: OperatorFunction<T, U>,
        ): Observable<unknown>;

        pipe<A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V>(
            op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>,
            op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>,
            op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>,
            op4: OperatorFunction<C, D>,
            op5: OperatorFunction<D, E>,
            op6: OperatorFunction<E, F>,
            op7: OperatorFunction<F, G>,
            op8: OperatorFunction<G, H>,
            op9: OperatorFunction<H, I>,
            op10: OperatorFunction<I, J>,
            op11: OperatorFunction<J, K>,
            op12: OperatorFunction<K, L>,
            op13: OperatorFunction<L, M>,
            op14: OperatorFunction<M, N>,
            op15: OperatorFunction<N, O>,
            op16: OperatorFunction<O, P>,
            op17: OperatorFunction<P, Q>,
            op18: OperatorFunction<Q, R>,
            op19: OperatorFunction<R, S>,
            op20: OperatorFunction<S, T>,
            op21: OperatorFunction<T, U>,
            op22: OperatorFunction<U, V>,
        ): Observable<unknown>;

        pipe<A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W>(
            op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>,
            op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>,
            op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>,
            op4: OperatorFunction<C, D>,
            op5: OperatorFunction<D, E>,
            op6: OperatorFunction<E, F>,
            op7: OperatorFunction<F, G>,
            op8: OperatorFunction<G, H>,
            op9: OperatorFunction<H, I>,
            op10: OperatorFunction<I, J>,
            op11: OperatorFunction<J, K>,
            op12: OperatorFunction<K, L>,
            op13: OperatorFunction<L, M>,
            op14: OperatorFunction<M, N>,
            op15: OperatorFunction<N, O>,
            op16: OperatorFunction<O, P>,
            op17: OperatorFunction<P, Q>,
            op18: OperatorFunction<Q, R>,
            op19: OperatorFunction<R, S>,
            op20: OperatorFunction<S, T>,
            op21: OperatorFunction<T, U>,
            op22: OperatorFunction<U, V>,
            op23: OperatorFunction<V, W>,
        ): Observable<unknown>;

        pipe<A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X>(
            op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>,
            op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>,
            op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>,
            op4: OperatorFunction<C, D>,
            op5: OperatorFunction<D, E>,
            op6: OperatorFunction<E, F>,
            op7: OperatorFunction<F, G>,
            op8: OperatorFunction<G, H>,
            op9: OperatorFunction<H, I>,
            op10: OperatorFunction<I, J>,
            op11: OperatorFunction<J, K>,
            op12: OperatorFunction<K, L>,
            op13: OperatorFunction<L, M>,
            op14: OperatorFunction<M, N>,
            op15: OperatorFunction<N, O>,
            op16: OperatorFunction<O, P>,
            op17: OperatorFunction<P, Q>,
            op18: OperatorFunction<Q, R>,
            op19: OperatorFunction<R, S>,
            op20: OperatorFunction<S, T>,
            op21: OperatorFunction<T, U>,
            op22: OperatorFunction<U, V>,
            op23: OperatorFunction<V, W>,
            op24: OperatorFunction<W, X>,
        ): Observable<unknown>;

        pipe<A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y>(
            op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>,
            op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>,
            op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>,
            op4: OperatorFunction<C, D>,
            op5: OperatorFunction<D, E>,
            op6: OperatorFunction<E, F>,
            op7: OperatorFunction<F, G>,
            op8: OperatorFunction<G, H>,
            op9: OperatorFunction<H, I>,
            op10: OperatorFunction<I, J>,
            op11: OperatorFunction<J, K>,
            op12: OperatorFunction<K, L>,
            op13: OperatorFunction<L, M>,
            op14: OperatorFunction<M, N>,
            op15: OperatorFunction<N, O>,
            op16: OperatorFunction<O, P>,
            op17: OperatorFunction<P, Q>,
            op18: OperatorFunction<Q, R>,
            op19: OperatorFunction<R, S>,
            op20: OperatorFunction<S, T>,
            op21: OperatorFunction<T, U>,
            op22: OperatorFunction<U, V>,
            op23: OperatorFunction<V, W>,
            op24: OperatorFunction<W, X>,
            op25: OperatorFunction<X, Y>,
        ): Observable<unknown>;

        pipe<A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z>(
            op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>,
            op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>,
            op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>,
            op4: OperatorFunction<C, D>,
            op5: OperatorFunction<D, E>,
            op6: OperatorFunction<E, F>,
            op7: OperatorFunction<F, G>,
            op8: OperatorFunction<G, H>,
            op9: OperatorFunction<H, I>,
            op10: OperatorFunction<I, J>,
            op11: OperatorFunction<J, K>,
            op12: OperatorFunction<K, L>,
            op13: OperatorFunction<L, M>,
            op14: OperatorFunction<M, N>,
            op15: OperatorFunction<N, O>,
            op16: OperatorFunction<O, P>,
            op17: OperatorFunction<P, Q>,
            op18: OperatorFunction<Q, R>,
            op19: OperatorFunction<R, S>,
            op20: OperatorFunction<S, T>,
            op21: OperatorFunction<T, U>,
            op22: OperatorFunction<U, V>,
            op23: OperatorFunction<V, W>,
            op24: OperatorFunction<W, X>,
            op25: OperatorFunction<X, Y>,
            op26: OperatorFunction<Y, Z>,
        ): Observable<unknown>;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought it'd be pretty interesting to point out that you can just chain `pipe`s indefinitely!

For instance, instead of doing:

```js
const source$: Observable<boolean> = of(true).pipe(
  tap(() => {}),
  tap(() => {}),
  tap(() => {}),
  tap(() => {}),
  tap(() => {}),
  tap(() => {}),
  tap(() => {}),
  tap(() => {}),
  tap(() => {}),
  // type inference is lost here
  tap(() => {}),
  tap(() => {}),
) as Observable<boolean>
```

... you can instead do:

```js
const source$: Observable<boolean> = of(true).pipe(
  tap(() => {}),
  tap(() => {}),
  tap(() => {}),
  tap(() => {}),
  tap(() => {}),
  tap(() => {}),
  tap(() => {}),
  tap(() => {}),
  tap(() => {}),
).pipe( // create a new pipe that allows you another 9 operators 
  tap(() => {}),
  tap(() => {}),
)
```